# Ввод данных с клавиатуры Java

Tags: java

Я сразу напишу, я новичек в Java, и язык знаю очень плохо. Пытался написать программу, но она выдает ошибку. Буду благодарен, если напишете, в чем я допустил ошибку. Вот код:

```
public class main {
    throws java.io.IOException {
        char x;
        x = (char) System.in.read();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы не пробовали прочитать учебник, а не тыкаться вслепую?

Comment: Уберите лишние фигурные скобки: после main и одну из двух последних

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать следующий синтаксис :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Используйте класс Scanner:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.next();
System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: Его код рабочий(для стандартного алфавита - где 256 символов). Ошибка не в способе чтения с консоли. Если подставить ваш код вместо его кода - вы все равно получите ошибку

Comment: @Miron Да, но новичку в любом случае рекомендуется использовать для ввода Scanner.